# Datagrab style plugin for importing CSV data to sections (Channels)

Tags: plugin-import

I use Datagrab on an EE site to import data to a Channel/fields and category assignment – is there an equivalent plugin or approach for Craft CMS, typically I want to allow the editor to import wine lists and display as listing pages (category title via EE e.g Burgundy) and click throughs from here to entry pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Datagrab, but from your description it sounds like the [Import plugin](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import) might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for that, I know some importers don't cater for CSV format but this looks good

Comment: check https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins?q=import for some other suggestions